# Wordpress: wp-cron not working and not giving error in log

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a wp-cron I defined in function.php file, but I don't get any result in the error log, the event is in the cron list but if I launch it nothing happens.
I have `define('WP_DEBUG', true);`
And error log enabled on all levels in php.ini

Does anybody know where am I doing wrong?

```
function cron_daily_whatever() {
  if (!wp_next_scheduled('check_daily_event')) {
    wp_schedule_event(time(),'daily','check_daily_event');
  }
}

function my_do_this_daily() {
    error_log('check');
}

add_action('wp','cron_daily_whatever');
add_action('check_daily_event','my_do_this_daily');
```

---

**SOLUTION**
I used the snippet

```
 file_put_contents(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/my-debug.txt', "Response: ".$res."\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

to debug it. And it now works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the default WP_DEBUG log in wp-content, you should define ('WP_DEBUG_LOG',TRUE); as well. Then you'll need to clear your scheduled event(and set it again) to test today if it has already run once. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_clear_scheduled_hook for that.

Comment: I have both active and there are no errors. I need to know if the call for registering the cron is correct...

Comment: Your methods look ok to me. Are you visiting the site to fire the cron? Are you able to log errors elsewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes I've it in the function.php and I can see the event between the other events in the wp-cron schedule table... The event fires but nothing happens, so I think there is no connection between the daily event and the function I'm trying to launch... :/ I can't undestand the reason...

Comment: Ok. First, I want to clarify your statement. I don't think you know 'The event fires'. Personally, I would debug this way: add a line to write to the error_log in some function in your function.php file that you do know for certain will be called and make sure your error logging is working. If it is, clear the scheduled hook and reset it. Then visit your site to fire the cron and check the log.

Answer (score 2):

seems you are having / setting the cron at page level / theme level ?

If you are setting at the plugin level.

```
add_action( 'my_hourly_event',  'update_db_hourly' );

public static function activate() {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'hourly', 'my_hourly_event' );
}

public static function deactivate() {
    wp_clear_scheduled_hook('my_hourly_event');
}

public function update_db_hourly() {

    // 1. Check for a new file
    // 2. If it exists, read it, upload it, delete it
    // 3. Otherwise, do nothing

}
```

Ref: https://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/

Note: If error_log is not working, can be due to some WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY=false flag not set properly. Better log a custom logging using the following snippet.

```
file_put_contents(WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/my-debug.txt', "Response **".$res."**", FILE_APPEND);
```

This file will get created under wp-content folder.